# Why transparency is shown as a chessboard pattern?

Tags: images

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28graphic%29)

> A suitable raster graphics editor shows transparency by a special
>   pattern, e.g. a chessboard pattern.

1. I wonder why complete transparency is shown as chessboard pattern?
   Is it chosen deliberately by people, or just a natural appearance of
   transparency under some circumstances?
2. How shall one distinguish an image which is actually a chessboard
   from an image with complete transparency?

Thanks!

Comment: It makes it easy to recognize, with transparency also shown via pink, since if transparency was shown as transparent, it would be difficult to recognize

Answer (score 7):

1. It's tradition.
2. By inspecting the pixel values or superimposing the image over a background, or by zooming in and observing that the chequerboard spacing is unaffected.

Comment: Why is it a tradition?

Comment: @Tim: for the same reasons that the Utah Teapot is a tradition.

Comment: You can. Viewers with zoom functionality (e.g. mostly all) will not zoom into the chessboard pattern, while enlarging the image.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: thanks, answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. If an application would show transparency as a specific colour, you would never know whether an area is transparant or just happens to have that colour. If the application would show the background through the image, you still wouldn't know whether the image happened to contain the background colour. Therefore it has to be a pattern, not a solid colour. A chessboard pattern happens to be less common in images than, for instance, diagonal shading.
2. As @RedGrittyBrick said, zoom in or out to check. The chessboard patterns will remain constant.